# Any way to track "load abandonment"?

Tags: asp.net, logging, analytics, tracking

**Question:** Is there any way to track how many website visitors are leaving your site because it takes too long to load?

Running IIS (not sure the version), ASP.NET 1.1, Proprietary Compiled & Obfuscated CMS.

**Background:** I'm currently working for a conglomerate of 20 companies, and about 8 of their websites are running a proprietary CMS based on ASP.NET 1.1 developed by a local company.

Those sites will frequently not load at all, crash the web server, or take an unacceptable time to load (45 seconds to 1 minute is common).

Comment: If you wanna make the big bucks, convince them to move to Sharepoint instead. Note: this is not an endorsement of Sharepoint.

Comment: I thought he said he wanted to move 'away' from a slow loading site... :) J/K

Comment: I'm afraid any big bucks I'll be making will have to come from that king's fortune my long-lost Nigerian uncle left me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log all the visits to the site using [iis logging](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b344f84e-bc77-4019-859c-9d483bc85c77.mspx?mfr=true) either to a file or directly into SQL.

Then you could query the data to see the average time a user spends on the site, how many only go to one page and so on.

If page load times are at the 10 second plus range your are [in big trouble](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Google Analytics and track the average time spent on a site/page?  Time less than 1 or 2 minutes would mean that you are not capturing your audience.

Comment: The problem is that Google Analytics never fires, because the ASP.NET application takes forever to start up. If there is a solution, it probably would require server-side logging or something. I suppose I could load a plain index.html file with ga.js, then 301 redirect to default.aspx, then compare pageviews between the two...but that seems dangerous SEO-wise, and doesn't account for direct traffic to anything but the homepage.

Comment: Good point, I suppose IIS log parsing is in your near future :) err... :/